# C++ Drawing arrays with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to the "new OpenGL" method of doing things.

I think that I have misunderstood, or not understood some of the steps for drawing data with OpenGL.

Assuming that I can open an OpenGL context, please could you (a SO user reading this question) clarify all the steps required to render an array of points describing a line in OpenGL.

Currently I have been doing this:

```
// In main:
float* my_points = new float[100];
// Fill my_points with some data to be drawn as a continuous line on the screen in x-y space.



// Inside esMainLoop, inside drawing function:
GLfloat* points = new GLfloat[3 * 100]; // x,, y, z points
// Copy data to points

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, points); // No idea what this is or how it works
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 100);



// In function called when CTRL+C is pressed:
delete my_points;
```

Previously (years ago) I have used things like glBindBuffers, glGenBuffers, etc. I don't understand these things either or if I need them, hence the question.

Comment: See [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tutorial%2001.html) for a great tutorial on how to proram retained mode OpenGL. It's very well worth the read.

Comment: I also recommend http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ for learning modern OpenGL

Comment: Thanks guys, I will also have a look at these.

Comment: If anyone wants to gain some extra rep / help me out, feel encouraged to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** updated the program to display data that changes over time

The program below produces a window with a rotating white rectangle from an array in OpenGL 3.2+ :

[image: rotating rectangle]

Apart from a few `glBind...(0)` calls, the example is minimal - drawing simple things the "new" way in OpenGL is unfortunately pretty involved.

```
#include "gl2stuff.h"

int main()
{
  if (!glfwInit())                                                                                                                        
    return -1;                                                                                                                            
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,2);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  GLFWwindow* window(glfwCreateWindow(200,150,"", NULL,NULL));
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  // points for a 2D rectangle
  GLfloat points[]={-0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5};
  GLfloat nPoints=5;

  /* vertex shader: read an array of 2D-points
     in the input attribute "vertex" and just pass
     them on as your position in the [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1]
     viewing volume
  */
  const char* vShader =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 vertex;"
    "void main() {gl_Position = vec4(vertex,0,1);}";
  /* fragment shader:
     draw everything in white
  */
  const char* fShader =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;"
    "void main() {color=vec4(1,1,1,1);}";

  /* create an OpenGL program, compile the shaders, 
     attach them to the program and link 
  */
  GLuint program(glCreateProgram());
  GLuint vertexShader(glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
  GLuint fragmentShader(glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vShader, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fShader, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(program);

  /* create a vertex buffer object (VBO)
     for your data and transfer the data
     from host memory to GPU memory
  */
  GLuint vBuffer;
  glGenBuffers(1,&vBuffer);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vBuffer);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(points),points,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

  // generate vertex array object (VAO)
  GLuint vertexArray;
  glGenVertexArrays(1,&vertexArray);

  /* enable attribute array for "vertex" in your
     shader and bind vBuffer to it; a VAO must
     be bound while doing this (this stores the
     the information about the vertex attributes;
     you can conveniently switch between multiple
     VAOs, but you need at least one)
  */
  glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
  GLuint vertexLocation(GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(program,"vertex")));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vBuffer);
  glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0 );
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);                                                           
  glBindVertexArray(0);

  /* finally we are ready to draw; 
     before drawing, make sure you call glUseProgram()
     and bind the correct VAO. If there is only one
     program and/or VAO it's ok if you just do these once 
     before you enter your drawing loop
  */
  glUseProgram(program);
  glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

  while(true)
    {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, nPoints);
      glfwSwapBuffers(window);

      // modify data and update buffer
      double t(glfwGetTime());
      points[0]=cos(t)*0.5;points[1]=sin(t)*0.5;
      points[2]=cos(t+1.57)*0.5;points[3]=sin(t+1.57)*0.5;
      points[4]=cos(t+3.14)*0.5;points[5]=sin(t+3.14)*0.5;
      points[6]=cos(t+4.71)*0.5;points[7]=sin(t+4.71)*0.5;
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vBuffer);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(points),points,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

    } 
  glBindVertexArray(0); 
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that this program is just for illustration. Normally, you would pass a time uniform to the shader and let the shader handle the rotation!

Comment: Thanks, I will read through this again today as it helps orient my thinking. What I was really interested in though was drawing the contents of an array which can change. For example, you have drawn a box, whereas I would be interested in drawing a moving box or a rotating box or something like that. (I am actually drawing a graph.) The key part being I don't know how to tell OpenGL that the array of points has changed, and then how to get OpenGL to draw the new array rather than the one it already has in graphics memory. If you want to modify it then I might be able to accept this as an...

Comment: ... answer, but I will give you a +1 anyway. Also to anyone reading this it might have been better to draw a box with GL_LINE_LOOP, but I think Roberto was using what I already had provided and hadn't realized I was drawing a line which does not connect back to itself.

Comment: Displaying a changing array takes only a minor addition (see edited program): You have to update your array and then call `glBufferData` again. If only a part of your array changes, look at `glBufferSubData` or `glMapBufferRange` to avoid uploading the whole array all the time; also, I changed the code to use LINE_LOOP

Comment: Did you lose interest? This answer is exactly what you asked for, and I would not mind at least some of the reputation that you repeatedly promised coming my way.

Comment: I haven't got round to implementing the changes yet or reading your updated answer, I will review it at some point in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(index​, size​, type​, normalized​, stride​, pointer​);
```

This function takes the currently bound `GL_VERTEX_BUFFER` and tells opengl where to find the data for vertex attribute at the specified `index`

in particular `points` is the offset from the beginning of the buffer, if the default buffer 0 is bound then it references the program memory in this case it points to the `points` array

`type` indicates the type of the binary data in the buffer, `size` is how many data elements belong to a single vertex and `normalized` tells opengl whether to map the integer values need to be mapped to 0.0-1.0